# Open mailto link and close page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to have a page open a `mailto` link and immediately close the page which opened that link? Right now I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       window.location.href = "mailto:test@domain.com";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a href="mailto:test@domain.com">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to that page, the mail client is opened but then page stays open which I would rather not have.

Comment: Just add `window.close()` after the open script.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I tried doing that but it didn’t work (the window remained open). EDIT: Using Firefox if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window.close() function which is works well whatever your browser is.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       //window.location.href = "mailto:test@domain.com";
       function openClose(url){
           newTab = window.open(url) // Default open target is "_blank" aka new tab
           newTab.close() // Window class have this method
           // Automatically close the tab when email client starts
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a onclick="openClose('mailto:test@domain.com')" href="#">Test</a>
     <!-- i set the "href" to "#" because of nothing :) -->
</body>
</html>
```